# How to do you separate or do you separate a Player/Non Player movement, action, behavior states in one or more component?

Tags: fsm, entity-component-system

Assume we are using Finite State Machine, what is the best way to organize states?

Given I have current `StateComponent`, all states are here.

```
MOVEMENT (Parallel) - Can be for player and non player
        [stand, walk, run]
        [forward, backward]
        [left, right]
        [jump, attack]
BEHAVIOR - For non player only
       [patrol, follow, chase, evade]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `BEHAVIOR` should *control* the `MOVEMENT` state, belonging to a different component. The `MOVEMENT` part I tend to call a `Controllable` which can be assigned to a `Player`, or have a `Brain` (`BEHAVIOUR`) component added to the same node, which then sets the controls in a `Think` function.